# Method to send repeated command between two Raspberry Pis c++

Tags: c++, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to write a program where I type a command in one Pi and then it gets sent to the other Pi. I want to have two similar programs running in parallel. With the code I have below I can get the Pis to connect and I can send 1 command, they both execute and return to the section where I can send the command, but the client hangs there, at the sleep_for(1s) section. I am relatively new to using communication so any help is appreciated.

Most of what I have tried has involved moving the part of the code that establishes the connection out of the while loop. But as I said I'm unfamiliar with how this type of communication works so I've been focusing on trying to understand it more.

Client

```
int main () {
    time_t start_time = 0;
    time_t now_time = 0;
    int loop = 1;
    int Step = 1;
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "169.254.220.0", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0){
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    }
    while (loop == 1){
        if(Step == 1){
            sleep_for(1s);
            while(Step == 10){
                printf("Listening");
                while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0){
                    recvBuff[n] = 0;
                    if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF){
                        printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
                    }
                }
                if(n < 0){
                    printf("\n Read error \n");
                }
                Step = atoi(recvBuff);
                cout << "Step = " << Step << "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (Step == 2){
            printf("2\n");
            Step = 1;
        }
        else if (Step == 15){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            Step = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
int main () {
    time_t start_time = 0;
    time_t now_time = 0;
    int loop = 1;
    int Step = 1;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char sendBuff[1025];
    printf("Here's johnny");
    cout << "\nStep A: " << Step << "\n";
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(listenfd, 10);
    while (loop == 1){

        if(Step == 1){
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
            cout << "Step ? ";
            cin >> Step;
            cout << "\n Step B: " << Step << "\n";
            snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%d", Step);
            write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
            close(connfd);
            printf("closed\n");
        }
        else if (Step == 2){
            printf("2\n");
            Step = 1;
        }
        else if (Step == 15){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            Step = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting an output of the number that I input as a step, 2, showing me that the code went to the correct step based on the input, and I get that on the first attempt, but after that first input the code hangs itself.

Comment: See **Backdoor shells** here... https://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(Step == 1){
        sleep_for(1s);
        while(Step == 10){
```

We only pass the `if` if `Step` is 1. But we only enter the `while` loop if `Step` is 10, which it never will be since it had to be 1 or we wouldn't have gotten to the `while` in the first place. So the code inside the `while` loop will not execute.

```
            while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0){
                recvBuff[n] = 0;
                if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF){
                    printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
                }
            }
```

This is broken. Each iteration of the `while` loop overwrites the previously received bytes. If the message being sent is "10" and the first `read` gets the "1", the second read that gets the "0" will overwrite the "1" and the `atoi` call will get 0 instead of 10!